# Statistics: Permutation Combinations

Tags: statistics

1) Among the seven nominees for two vacancies on the city council are three men and four
women. In how many ways may these vacancies be filled

a, with any two of the nominees?

b, with any two of the women?

c, with one of the men and one of the women?

*My Solutions*

Part a, 7C2 = 21

Part b, 4C2 x 3C0 = 6

Part c, 3C1 x 4c1 = 12

---

2) There are five finalists in the Mr. St. Hill’s pageant. In how many ways can the judges
choose a winner and a first runner-up?

*My Solution:*

5P2 = 20

---

3) How many 4-digit numbers can be made using the digits 6,7,2,3,5,9,8, if there are to be no repetitions of numbers?

*My Solution:*

7P4 = 840

***This is an assignment I am doing and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes, sorry for the layout of the numbers. I'm not good at doing the layouts on here.
Thank you***

Comment: Any assistance ?

Comment: I think it looks fine. Though, I've been wrong before. Haha.